# Casting a System.Func<T>

Tags: c#, generics, func

I am re-factoring some code which uses the following construct. What I'd like to be able to do is make this generic so I can have other parameter types in the Func.

```
IDictionary<string, Func<Employee, string>>
```

I tried using:

```
IDictionary<string, Func<Object, string>>
```

Then casting it back:

```
(IDictionary<string, Func<Object, string>>)myDictionary
```

But I get an exception saying I am not able to cast

> Unable to cast object of type'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Func`2...

I been playing around with generics but that only seems to get me so far as I not able to setup and generic field on my class

```
private IDictionary<string, Func<T, string>> lineSpecification;
```

Been going around in circles so any pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the full exception message I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Func`2[DataObjects.Employee,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.
```

Answer (score 5):

That wouldn't be type-safe.

Had that been legal, what would happen if you passed a `Car` to one of the casted values (which is really a `Func<Employee, string>`)?

Answer (score 2):

Instead type the Dictionary as 
`IDictionary<string, object>` 
and cast the resultant value:

```
IDictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var myDelegate = (Func<Employee, string>)myDictionary["my employee delegate"];
```

Of course, this will fail if you try to cast the wrong Func type, so you should be sure you know which keys map to which Func types.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your dictionary to have values of varying type; in other words, that a single dictionary might hold a `Func<Employee, string>` and a `Func<Customer, string>`.

If that is so, then you basically have no choice but to use a common base type for the `TValue` type argument, and cast the delegates when you retrieve them from the dictionary.  The common base type could be `System.Delegate` or `System.Object`.

(There are in fact other choices than this, but they just push the casting around to a different part of the design.  For example, you could write a wrapper class that handles the casting for you.  Such solutions don't generally stand up to a cost-benefit analysis, though.)

> My dictionary will only ever hold the same type, but in different scenarios I want it to be able to hold different types. The problem I have is casting from Func to Func throws the casting exception.

In that case, it's not clear why you want to have a `Dictionary<string, Func<Object, string>>` rather than a `Dictionary<string, Func<Employee, string>>`.  If any given dictionary will only hold one type of delegate, then create the dictionary accordingly:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Employee, string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Func<Employee, string>>();
```

If the dictionary is a member of a generic class, or a local variable or parameter of a generic method, you can use type parameters in the dictionary's declaration:

```
class Processor<T>
{
     void Process(T value, Dictionary<string, Func<T, string>> functions) { //... }
}
```

Comment: My dictionary will only ever hold the same type, but in different scenarios I want it to be able to hold different types. The problem I have is casting from Func<Object, string> to Func<Employee, string> throws the casting exception.

Comment: @bigtv why do you want to cast it?  What do you mean by "different scenarios"?  I added some thoughts; I'll add more if you can clarify.